# $(this) not working within if ($(".element").is()

Tags: javascript, jquery

My expected result for the code below is `.csr-area-3 .csr-video` with added classes `csr-animate csr-zoom-in`, why does `$(this)` not work in this situation?

```
if ($(".csr-area-3 .csr-video").is(":in-viewport")) {
    $(this).addClass('csr-animate csr-zoom-in');
}
```

Comment: Why should it? You expect the context to be the `if` condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`.filter(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), to get the matched element which are in-view port and then add class to then

```
$(".csr-area-3 .csr-video").filter(function() {
    return $(this).is(":in-viewport");
}).addClass('csr-animate csr-zoom-in');
```

You could also use

```
$(".csr-area-3 .csr-video:in-viewport").addClass('csr-animate csr-zoom-in');
```

Answer (score 7):

Because the context is the caller function / event or maybe the global window context, use the same selector again in order to add the class:

```
if ($(".csr-area-3 .csr-video").is(":in-viewport")) {
    $(".csr-area-3 .csr-video").addClass('csr-animate csr-zoom-in');
}
```

---

**Edit from comments**

Use a variable to store the results of the jquery lookup:

```
var csrvideo = $(".csr-area-3 .csr-video");
if (csrvideo.is(":in-viewport")) {
    csrvideo.addClass('csr-animate csr-zoom-in');
}
```

**Note:** using filter as @saptal's answer will assure the class to be added to the element(s) within viewport in case multiple elements exist.

Comment: That is what I have been doing, but I ideally don't want to repeat the code and change the number for each one.

Comment: do it in a loop then :)

Comment: make an array of all needed elements, loop through them and addClass on each element

Comment: You can save the jquery object in a variable and use it so that the selector won't be executed twice, or you can use filter as @satpal stated in his answer that where `this` would refer to a `csr-area/csr-video` element

Comment: Incorrect, If there are multiple elements with matching selector  then even if only one `csr-video` is in view port, the above code will add classes to all element. not to only the element in view port.

Comment: yes true if there are multiple elements in the class.. will update

Comment: Yes this was to be used for multiple elements of .csr-video, using .filter I can now remove the .csr-area-x

Comment: Yeah but this was unclear in the question.. thought it is good to cover all cases... We might assume that a class references multiple elements but this does not have to be true all the time, depending on its usage in the markup

Answer (score 1):

If you only use

```
$(this).someFunction();
```

`this` refers to the `window` object.

You need to do

```
$(".csr-area-3:in-viewport").addClass('csr-animate csr-zoom-in');
$(".csr-video:in-viewport").addClass('csr-animate csr-zoom-in');
```

(Depends on what you actually want)